# Configuring a Dell Chromebook to suspend in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chromebook

I recently acquired a new Dell Chromebook 11, and I'm having issues with the suspend functionality in Ubuntu. More specifically, when I run `sudo pm-suspend`, the system simply shutsdown.
Ubuntu was installed through the commonly used [chrubuntu scripts](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2013/10/chrubuntu-for-new-chromebooks-now-with.html) that have worked well for people with other Chromebooks. However, patches and configs that have worked so well for the Acer c720 and the HP Chromebook 14, seem to not apply to the Dell. I've done a bit of digging around, and haven't seen any solutions targeted at my exact hardware and distro choices.
Archlinux has a [dedicated wikipage for the Dell Chromebook](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_Chromebook_11) however, the directions found there need to be ported to work with Ubuntu.
I also found a good blog on setting up Elementary OS (an Ubuntu derivative) on an HP Chromebook 14 (superuser won't allow me to post more links). Following those directions got me nowhere.

Comment: You can try the Arch instructions, but you will need an [Upstart job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) instead of the systemd service.

Comment: @fooot Thanks for the lead. I'll look into that!